# Spring Integration - object placed in header is returned as String rather than the object type

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I've got an integration flow written in the Java DSL

I'm enriching the header of a message to include an AtomicInteger:

```
.enrichHeaders(t -> t.headerFunction(pollTime,message -> new AtomicInteger()))
```

If I put a breakpoint on the subsequent handle method in the same flow I can see the  header and it's a String not an AtomicInteger.

So if I try to retrieve it in another flow like so I get an illegal argument exception:

```
message.getHeaders().get(pollTime,AtomicInteger.class).getAndAdd(delay);


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect type specified for header 'pollTime'. Expected [class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger] but actual type is [class java.lang.String]
```

If I do the same thing in the Kotlin DSL it all works fine:

```
       enrichHeaders {
            headerFunction<Any>(pollCount) {
                AtomicInteger()
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps you have something else in the flow which converts your headers to strings. Please, share with us more code to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

I created a stand alone project to reproduce the error, and that added in the header as an expected AtomicInteger.

Then I debugged our main application and it turns out there's an  OpenTracingChannelInterceptor which is re-writing all headers as Strings.

This library is the culprit:

`io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-messaging:0.0.5` which is transitive dependency of `io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-cloud-starter-jaeger`

It looks like adding this library just breaks Spring Integration.

The fix is to exclude the tracing autoconfiguration:

`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {OpenTracingChannelInterceptorAutoConfiguration.class})`

Update:

The opentracing library is now longer maintained so the long term fix for this would be to migrate to a different tracing library that hopefully doesn't have the same type of issue.

See

https://www.cncf.io/blog/2022/01/31/cncf-archives-the-opentracing-project/